# Blank basket inshopping cart yii after refresh page

Tags: php, yii, shopping-cart

I have some bproblem with basket in shopping cart yii.When I refresh or going to another page all goods are remove from basket? How I can fix it?

Comment: That's not a real question... how are you storing those items?

Comment: I implement my Moderl from IECartPosition set getPrice and getId method's and in the controller when I add good to basket: `$model =Goods::model()->FindByPk($id); Yii::app()->shoppingCart->put($model)`-that is all that I did.